# exercise 7.2: Think Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, estimation, square-root

"Encapsulate this loop in a function called square_root that takes a as a parameter, chooses a reasonable value of x, and returns an estimate of the square root of a."

```
def square_root(a):
    x = 2 
    y = (x + a/x) / 2
    epsilon = 0.00000000001
    if abs(y - x) < epsilon:
        print y
    while abs(y - x) > epsilon: 
        x = x + 1
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
        break
    else:
        return
    print y     
square_root(33)
```

up to putting 33 for 'a', it estimates the correct square root. after that, it starts jumping exponentially, to the point where when I send 100 in for 'a', it guesses the square root to be approximately 18. I don't know if maybe this is the nature of estimating. I know of how to find the precise square root, but this is an exercise from the book "Think Python" and it's to practice with recursion and thinking algorithmically.

Comment: Why do you have a `break` directly in the body of your `while` loop?

Comment: it wouldn't give me anything otherwise, just blank. It would run, but wouldn't print 'y'

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be incrementing `x` by 1 in the loop body. You should be setting `x` to `y` (look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number) and notice how `x3` depends on `x2`, and so on):

```
while abs(y - x) > epsilon:
    x = y
    y = (x + a/x) / 2
```

You want to get rid of that `break` as well, as it makes your `while` loop pointless. Your final code will then be:

```
def square_root(a):
    x = 2 
    y = (x + a/x) / 2
    epsilon = 0.00000000001
    if abs(y - x) < epsilon:
        print y
    while abs(y - x) > epsilon: 
        x = y
        y = (x + a/x) / 2
    print y
```

But there's still room for improvement. Here's how I'd write it:

```
def square_root(a, epsilon=0.001):
    # Initial guess also coerces `a` to a float
    x = a / 2.0

    while True:
        y = (x + a / x) / 2

        if abs(y - x) < epsilon:
            return y

        x = y
```

Also, since Python's floating point type doesn't have infinite precision, you can only get about 15 digits of precision anyways, so you might as well just remove `epsilon`:

```
def square_root(a):
    x = a / 2.0

    while True:
        y = (x + a / x) / 2

        # You've reached Python's max float precision
        if x == y:
            return x

        x = y
```

But this last version might not terminate if y oscillates between two values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way; it just updates x instead of using a y.

```
 def square_root(a):
    x = a / 2.0
    epsilon = 0.00000001
    while abs(a - (x**2)) > epsilon:
        x = (x + a/x) / 2
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it more abstract create good-enough? and guess as primitives .. Refer to the classic text of SICP here http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node108.html

Answer (score 0):

so simple , just take x = a and then follow neuton formula , like this :

```
def square_root(a):
x = a
while True:
    print x
    y = (x+a/x)/2
    if abs(y-x) < 0.0000001:
        break
    x = y
```